# GitLab Enterprise edition Upgrade paths

Tags: gitlab

In GitLab documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/13.6/ee/update/README.html they specified the Gitlab upgrade path.

[image]

But, it's only up to 13.5.3. Now the stable version is 13.8.1 Could someone please help to get the exact upgrade path/chain to upgrade Gitlab from 13.5.3 to 13.8.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest always looking at the [latest version of the docs page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/README.html#upgrade-paths), which says:

> 8.11.x -> 8.12.0 -> 8.17.7 -> 9.5.10 -> 10.8.7 -> 11.11.8 -> 12.0.12 -> 12.1.17 -> 12.10.14 -> 13.0.14 -> 13.1.11 - > 13.x (latest)

So you should in fact be able to go from 13.1.11 to 13.8.1.

Just note that the doc page covers [specific version upgrade notes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/README.html#version-specific-upgrading-instructions), and the different upgrade path if you want to do it [without downtime](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/README.html#upgrading-without-downtime).

Comment: yes, I already created a ticket with the GitLab community https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-enterprise-edition-upgrade-paths/48061/2 , and based on that, they updated the documentation page as above one.